# Link_to & Routes Relation: How to customize a hard path within LinkTo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Couldn't find answer searched everywhere. Maybe I am using rails incorrectly.

1. I have made a custom route:

   get "/posts/:page/category/:query" => 'posts#index', as: :posts_category
2. As you can see above I have customized in my route a path with a 'category' string within it.
3. How do I use link_to to address this.
4. I have tried

   link_to posts_category(:page=>1, :query=>3)

This doesn't work because the link created by rails does NOT include the the /category/ within the path. How do I add that in the link_to.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine (although I'm assuming it was a typo that you wrote `posts_category()` instead of `posts_category_path()`), so maybe you have another route defined earlier in your `routes.rb` with the same helper name, it will be masking this one.

Run `rake routes` and look for something else with the `posts_category` helper.

Comment: I am confused regarding the purposes of the routes.rb file. It seems it isn't need as any controller can grab parameters via params[:item].  Besides leveraging the url helpers ("posts_path" within the link_to function) and having nicer looking URLS, is there any other real advantage.

Comment: Mapping nice looking URLs to controllers (and generating nice helper methods) is precisely the purpose of the `routes.rb`